Plex on Synology on Samsung TVs - Cannot enable Sync Watch State and Rating (only on admin account)
I've searched the internet and found no one with the following issue:
I cannot enable 'Sync Watch State and Rating' on my Samsung Smart TVs (2 of them) when using my main (admin) account on the Plex TV App. Now this issue does NOT exist for any other accounts I made (for my girlfriend or my moms accounts).
Why would this only affect my admin account AND only on my TVs (not on my PC when use webapp)?
I get this error on my TV debug menu:

ERROR Failed to set VSS consent Http request failed: https//plex.tv/api/v2/user/view_state_sync`, status: 403

Picture of the debug message:

Info:

Plex server: on Synology NAS (running DSM 7)
Server Version: 1.40.2.8395
Player Version: 4.130.0


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It’s perfectly normal for options to be different between an Administrator account and an unprivileged account. In this case the http request failed. If unprivileged accounts work I suspect this might be intentional even if it’s not straightforward

It's weird becasue I don't have this issue on my Android Plex app when using the admin account. I'm thinking of deleting the Plex volume on my NAS and re-installing it. I'm wondering if this is a result of upgrading Synology DSM 6 to 7.

Before you do that, create a new privileged user, see if the issue follows escalated permissions

Unfortunately in Plex only one account can be admin with privileges. Any other account you make you just choose what libraries they have access to. AND those work! I made one for my GF and mom recently, both of those accounts have no issue with saving watched states or ratings.

Is this perhaps an issue with the apps on the TVs? In my experience, Smart TV apps are updated slowly and often suffer from incompatibilities. Have you checked w/ Plex support regarding this?

Plex... does NOT offer any troubleshooting support. Instead you are directed to their community forms where I have opened this question up but received no answers yet, but I did this recently. I highly suspect this could be the case. I'll check on my mom's end becasue her install is on her Apple 2 TV.

Found  a solution! I bought a TV Fire Cube which doesn't have this problem and is much faster than Smart TVs app. This confirms it's a Samsung issue.
